# WordPress cannot write file to disk

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So my website was hacked a few days ago and after that I did a fresh install of wordpress.

I proceeded to install my theme, everything went smooth. But when I wanted to upload files in the media folder via wp, it said cannot write file to disk.

I tried a few more times and it worked, I uploaded like 5 images and it stopped working again  same error.

I also cannot install plugins via wp I have to do it manually, and I had to install my theme manually too... I  am going crazy called my web hosting they said it's wordpress fault.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to review permissions of `wp-content/*` folders and files and subfolders. Folders should be `755` to support writing into them by WordPress. You can set this in most FTP client software by use of `CHMOD` feature.

You may also need to review owning user and group of `wp-content/*` folders and subfolders and files. Owning user and group should match the Linux user and group that your server software operates under (i.e. user `www-data` or `apache`)

```
wp-content/uploads for media uploads, thumbnail image generation
wp-content/themes for theme installation, automatic updates, and use of Editor
wp-content/plugins for plugins installation, automatic updates, and use of Editor
```

Do you have SSH access into your server? That's easiest way to verify and change ownership user/group and permissions.

Comment: Depending on your configuration and the help you require beyond this, your question is probably better suited at Server Fault.

Comment: I dont have such access , I did call the webhosting service and told them about my problem they didnt reply yet 

before the hack when everything worked as it should , I used the same method to install wp .. create new db with a new user .